# How can i assign json.net linq method according to a condition

Tags: c#, json.net

When i try to use codes as below i am getting error as

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' and
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

```
    string J = "a";

    JArray _JArray = JArray.Parse(_JsonString);
    JObject _JObject = JObject.Parse(_JsonString);

    var _JlinQ = J == "a" ? _JArray : _JObject;

          var _JItems = _JlinQ .SelectToken(".")
                                 .Select(s => new
                                 {
                                     _Id = (string)s.SelectToken("id"),                           
                                     _WhereClause = (string)s.SelectToken("status")
                                 })
                                 .Where(w => w._WhereClause == "1");

                    foreach (var _JItem in _JItems)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(_JItem._Id.ToString());
                    }
```

is there any approach to use this codes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you have two different value types for the condition: var _JlinQ = J == "a" ? _JArray : _JObject;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
var _JlinQ = J == "a" ? (JContainer)_JArray : (JContainer)_JObject;
```